# Как установить в bower bxslider?

Tags: gulp, bower

Есть проект, как установить в него bxslider? 
И как при этом использовать --save-dev

Comment: Это чем-нибудь отличается от "как установить в bower что угодно"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bower install bxslider-4 --save-dev
```